# how can i check my applications total downloads and its other statistics published in both google play and apple's app store

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails

I want to check my application's total downloads, ratings, reviews and its other statistics thats published in both google play and apple's app store. Is there any api or something available from where i can use the data to customize it and use in my app my way...

Comment: If you don't have an Android app, then you don't have any downloads from Google Play. And if you don't have an iOS app, then you don't have any downloads from the App Store. What are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the statistics of Android Application, you can make use of Android MarketAPI here: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ . Its a direct SVN checkout. If you have Tortoise SVN in your machine, enter the path provided in the url under Source tab.

Comment: @Arvind do u find the solution?

Comment: Thanks Avadhani your link was also useful but i wanted something for  ios app also I have got the solution as my question has been put on hold i am posting the answer as a comment. There is a great analytical service AppFigures it tracks your application and delivers the results like total downloads, Rating , Review it also provides developers api which is very useful to grab our apps statistics and customise that data in our way.

Answer (score -1):

Through iTunes connect, we can only get weekly reports. Use the AppViz 2 to get the total downloads. It is a tool for getting statistics of sales. You can download the application [here](http://www.ideaswarm.com/AppViz2.html)

Comment: AppViz went out of business and abandoned all of their users.